# Flex 4.9.1 Fullscreen

Tags: flex4

I have a webapp built with Apache Flex 4.9.1 and I am trying to make a sub component of my main application fullscreen. I have tried the following code by my view size doesn't change.

```
        private function onFullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.removeElement(view);

            this.stage.getChildAt(0).visible = false;

            this.stage.addChild(view);
            view.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
            view.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;

            this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            this.stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, onFullScreenChange);
        }

        private function onFullScreenChange(event:FullScreenEvent):void
        {
            this.stage.removeEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, onFullScreenChange);
            if ( !event.fullScreen )
            {
                this.stage.getChildAt(0).visible = true;
                this.stage.removeChild(view);
                this.addElement(view);
                view.percentHeight = view.percentWidth = 100;
            }
        }
```

I have tried calling invalidate on the view but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you [allowed full screen mode in HTML](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_10.html)?

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Yes the component does show up in fullscreen but it doesn't resize to take up all the available space.

Comment: What happens if you set the width/height to 100%?

Comment: The component shows up with the original width and height. I ran it through the debugger and the component shows the proper width and height (fullscreenWidth and fullscreenHeight) but it's not updated on the screen. I've tried a invalidate but that didn't seem to help.